# Ubuntu 14 nodejs install with apt-get node fails to run in console

Tags: node.js, ubuntu

I have run sudo apt-get install nodejs and I expected that when I now type node in the terminal I would go into the node shell. or if I type node --version I would see the version instead nothing happens no errors, results, anything the terminal just goes to a new line like I pressed enter without typing anything. ive been googling for the last two hours and have found nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after a lot of looking I found a package called "node" installed which is some sort of radio package and has nothing to do with nodejs I believe it was causing conflicts particularly with web storm which I believe was picking up that package and getting very confused. after removing that everything was working again.

I also noted that I was typing node --version and I should have typed nodejs --version. Hopefully this helps someone else that accidentally installs the "node" amateur radio package

Answer (score 0):

Use this commands

```
sudo apt install curl
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_14.x | sudo bash -
sudo apt install -y nodejs
```